# JPA @Query with Entity like parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using a `@Query` with JPA in my Repository. But, when I execute a program which uses this @Query, I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'supplierRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract XXX.Supplier XXXXX.SupplierRepository.findByNumber(XXXXX.Supplier)!
```

This is the code with the query :

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Supplier WHERE s.number= :#{#supplier.number}")
Supplier findByNumber(@Param("supplier") Supplier supplier);
```

Why do I have this error?

Comment: Please provide your Supplier class code. I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide alias for entity as below:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Supplier s WHERE s.number= :#{#supplier.number}")
Supplier findByNumber(@Param("supplier") Supplier supplier);
```